# Symfony subquery for entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, subquery, symfony

Have a problem with subquery with symfony.

What I try to do - I have a table with users and a table with posts.

```
Posts                  Users
id|author|content     id|username
```

I want create subquery to get user name by id.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function findAll()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT a, (SELECT u.username
         FROM BackendBundle:User u WHERE u.id = a.author) as authorName
         FROM BackendBundle:Article a'
    )->getResult();
}
```

Result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to join column from other table by id? Maybe i can use annotations?

Thx for any help.

Comment: check the doc about the joins: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a subquery here, what you need is a simple (INNER) JOIN to join Users with their Articles.

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT a FROM Article JOIN a.author'");
```

You don't even need an on clause in your join, because Doctrine should already know (through annotations on your entities or a separate yaml file), that the article.author field relates to user.id.

**Edit:**

I assume you have a User entity that is One-To-Many related to the Article entity.

```
class User
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $articles;
    // ...
}

class Article
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @var User 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $author;
    // ...
}
```

Please refer to doctrines association mapping documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: I just want to join one column username from users table. To show article author name.

Comment: You want to say that i can join only whole entity but can't join only one column and bind value from that column to property in other entity?

Comment: Now my User object have no data :(
http://ssmaker.ru/c1b4d672/
What i'm doing wrong? I just want to have property authorName with string value :D

Comment: Maybe there is a reason to use a subselect. I would like to know as well how to map subselect to entity attribute, not how to join.